# How can filter any SET by its concat value according to another SET in Redis

Tags: lua, redis

I have a filter optimization problem in Redis.

I have a Redis SET which keeps the doc and pos pairs of a type in a corpus.

example:

```
smembers type_in_docs.1
```

result: doc.pos pairs

```
array (size=216627)
0 => string '2805.2339' (length=9)
1 => string '2410.14208' (length=10)
2 => string '3516.1810' (length=9)
...
```

Another redis set i create live according to user choices
It contains selected docs.

```
smembers filteredDocs
```

I want to filter **doc.pos** pairs **"type_in_docs"**  set according to user Doc id choices.
In fact if i didnt use concat values in set it was easy with **SINTER**.

So i implement a php filter code as below.
It works but need an optimization.
In big doc.pairs set too much time need. (Nearly After 150000 members!)

```
$concordance= $this->redis->smembers('types_in_docs.'.$typeID);
$filteredDocs= $this->redis->smembers('filteredDocs');

$filtered = array_filter($concordance, function($pairs) use ($filteredDocs) {
    if( in_array(substr($pairs, 0, strpos($pairs, '.')), $filteredDocs) ) return true;
   });
```

I tried sorted set with scores as docId.
Bu couldnt find a intersect or filter option for score values.

I am thinking and searching a Redis based solution with supported keys, sets or Lua script for time optimization.
But nothing find.

How can i filter Redis sets with concat values?

Thanks for helps.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is slow primarily because you're moving a lot of data from Redis to your PHP filter. The general motivation here should be perform as much filtering as possible on the server. To do that you'd need to pay some sort of price in CPU & RAM.

There are many ways to do this, here's one:

1. Ensure you're using Redis v2.8.9 or above.
2. To allow efficiently looking for `doc` only, keep your `doc.pos` pairs as is but use Sorted Sets with score = 0, your e.g.:

   ```
   ZADD type_in_docs.1 0 2805.2339 0 2410.14208 0 3516.1810
   ```

This will allow you to mimic `SISMEMBER` for `doc` in the set with:

```
    ZRANGEBYLEX type_in_docs.1 [<$typeID> (<$typeID + "\xff">
```

3. You can now just `SMEMBERS` on the (usually) smaller `filterDocs` set and then call `ZRANGEBYLEX` on each for immediate gains.
4. If you want to do better - in extreme cases (i.e. large `filterDocs`, small `type_in_docs`) you should do the reverse.
5. If you want to do even better, use Lua to wrap up the filtering logic - something like:

   ```
   -- @usage:  redis-cli --filter_doc_pos.lua <filter set keyname> <type pairs keyname> 
   -- @returns: list of matching doc.pos pairs 

   local r = {}

   for _, fv in pairs(redis.call("SMEMBERS", KEYS[1])) do
       local t = redis.call("ZRANGEBYLEX", KEYS[2], "[" .. fv , "(" .. fv .. "\xff")
       for _, tv in pairs(t) do
           r[#r+1] = tv
       end
   end

   return r
   ```

Comment: First of all thank you for your detailed methods, scripts and instant answer.
This methods are definetly what i need.
Method #5 spesifically what i want to learn and apply.
This method clear my mind in using lua scripts via redis.
It inspired me to use it another modules in my PhD project.
I execute lua your script via PHP Predis library.
Great success!
Thank you very very much...

Comment: I'm happy you liked it - feel free to contact me on anything Redis (+Lua) :) and don't forget making this as the answer...